# How do turn this Windows CMD command to a Batch File?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

```
"C:\Users\cswl\projs\warfram-websit\launcher\procgov64.exe"   --nogui --maxmem 2500M   "E:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Warframe\Warframe.x64.exe   -fullscreen:0 -dx10:0 -dx11:1 -threadedworker:1  -cluster:public -language:en"
```

I tried using `start` like this, but the parameters aren't being passed

```
start "" /b "%~dp0procgov64.exe"   --nogui --maxmem 2500M   E:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Warframe\Warframe.x64.exe ^
  -fullscreen:0 -dx10:0 -dx11:1 -threadedworker:1 ^
 -cluster:public -language:en
```

I need to pass parameters to `procgov64` which in turn passes the parameters to the executable `Warframe`.

Comment: Just paste it without any modifications and save the file. `cmd` literally executes batch files line by line.

Comment: In this specific case you likely could also just use a shotcut (link/lnk) as you're just running a single command with parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`%~dp0` expands to the full path of `%0`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5034076/995714), (i.e. the current folder), which is unnecessary. Just use a relative path like `procgov64.exe` or `.\procgov64.exe` if the file is in the current folder, otherwise replace the full path to the executable like `C:\foo\procgov64.exe`

And you don't actually need `start`, just run the command directly unless you need to wait for the program to close or when you need to use special options like changing the priority. If `procgov64.exe` is a console app, `start /b` is pointless

```
procgov64.exe --nogui --maxmem 2500M ^
    E:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Warframe\Warframe.x64.exe ^
    -fullscreen:0 -dx10:0 -dx11:1 -threadedworker:1 ^
    -cluster:public -language:en
```